# Using CSExeCOMServer how do I receive the event in VS C++

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2012, com

Starting with Microsoft's C# .NET CSExeCOMserver (out of proc EXE) example - I have the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;


namespace CSExeCOMServer
{
#region Interfaces

[Guid(CSSimpleObject.InterfaceId), ComVisible(true)]
public interface ICSSimpleObject
{
    #region Properties

    float FloatProperty { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    string HelloWorld();

    void GetProcessThreadID(out uint processId, out uint threadId);

    #endregion
}

[Guid(CSSimpleObject.EventsId), ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface ICSSimpleObjectEvents
{
    #region Events

    [DispId(1)]
    void FloatPropertyChanging(float NewValue, ref bool Cancel);

    #endregion
}

#endregion

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid(CSSimpleObject.ClassId)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]           // No ClassInterface
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(ICSSimpleObjectEvents))]
public class CSSimpleObject : ReferenceCountedObject, ICSSimpleObject
{
    #region COM Component Registration

    internal const string ClassId =
        "DB9935C1-19C5-4ed2-ADD2-9A57E19F53A3";
    internal const string InterfaceId =
        "941D219B-7601-4375-B68A-61E23A4C8425";
    internal const string EventsId =
        "014C067E-660D-4d20-9952-CD973CE50436";

    // These routines perform the additional COM registration needed by 
    // the service.

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [ComRegisterFunction()]
    public static void Register(Type t)
    {
        try
        {
            COMHelper.RegasmRegisterLocalServer(t);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); // Log the error
            throw ex; // Re-throw the exception
        }
    }

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [ComUnregisterFunction()]
    public static void Unregister(Type t)
    {
        try
        {
            COMHelper.RegasmUnregisterLocalServer(t);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); // Log the error
            throw ex; // Re-throw the exception
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    private float fField = 0;

    public float FloatProperty
    {
        get { return this.fField; }
        set
        {
            bool cancel = false;
            // Raise the event FloatPropertyChanging
            if (null != FloatPropertyChanging)
                FloatPropertyChanging(value, ref cancel);
            if (!cancel)
                this.fField = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "HelloWorld";
    }

    public void GetProcessThreadID(out uint processId, out uint threadId)
    {
        processId = NativeMethod.GetCurrentProcessId();
        threadId = NativeMethod.GetCurrentThreadId();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Events

    [ComVisible(false)]
    public delegate void FloatPropertyChangingEventHandler(float NewValue, ref bool Cancel);
    public event FloatPropertyChangingEventHandler FloatPropertyChanging;

    #endregion
}

/// <summary>
/// Class factory for the class CSSimpleObject.
/// </summary>
internal class CSSimpleObjectClassFactory : IClassFactory
{
    public int CreateInstance(IntPtr pUnkOuter, ref Guid riid, 
        out IntPtr ppvObject)
    {
        ppvObject = IntPtr.Zero;

        if (pUnkOuter != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            // The pUnkOuter parameter was non-NULL and the object does 
            // not support aggregation.
            Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(COMNative.CLASS_E_NOAGGREGATION);
        }

        if (riid == new Guid(CSSimpleObject.ClassId) ||
            riid == new Guid(COMNative.IID_IDispatch) ||
            riid == new Guid(COMNative.IID_IUnknown))
        {
            // Create the instance of the .NET object
            ppvObject = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(
                new CSSimpleObject(), typeof(ICSSimpleObject));
        }
        else
        {
            // The object that ppvObject points to does not support the 
            // interface identified by riid.
            Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(COMNative.E_NOINTERFACE);
        }

        return 0;   // S_OK
    }

    public int LockServer(bool fLock)
    {
        return 0;   // S_OK
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Reference counted object base.
/// </summary>
[ComVisible(false)]
public class ReferenceCountedObject
{
    public ReferenceCountedObject()
    {
        // Increment the lock count of objects in the COM server.
        ExeCOMServer.Instance.Lock();
    }

    ~ReferenceCountedObject()
    {
        // Decrement the lock count of objects in the COM server.
        ExeCOMServer.Instance.Unlock();
    }
}
}
```

The above registers and I output a test.tlb file just fine - I have a COM client that uses the above COM Server in standard visual C++ as follows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <objbase.h>
#include <comutil.h>

#import <C:\Users\ndavis\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\test.tlb> no_namespace named_guids

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

ULONG procID;
ULONG threadID;

//initialize COM for this thread
//HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

ICSSimpleObjectPtr pSimple_1;
hr = pSimple_1.CreateInstance(CLSID_CSSimpleObject, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER);
_bstr_t hw_response = pSimple_1->HelloWorld();
_bstr_t testID = pSimple_1->GetProcessThreadID(&procID, &threadID);

pSimple_1->FloatProperty = 1.7f;

CoUninitialize();

    return 0;

}
```

All the above works: pSimple_1->HelloWorld(); returns correct response, pSimple_1->GetProcessThreadID(...) returns correct response; and pSimple_1->FloatProperty = 1.7f sets the FloatProperty correctly.

QUESTION: How do I receive the FloatPropertyChanging(float value, bool* cancel) event in my visual C++ client code above? (please no ATL).

Thanks

Additional information that has gotten me a little farther - I have added the following to my code:

Adding the following class to my client:

```
class EventHandler : public ICSSimpleObjectEvents
{

public:
EventHandler(void) { }
~EventHandler(void) { }

HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface(const IID &, void **);
ULONG __stdcall AddRef(void) { return 1; }
ULONG __stdcall Release(void) { return 1; }

virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetTypeInfoCount(UINT * pTypeInfoCount) { return -1; }
virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetTypeInfo(UINT itinfo, LCID lcid, ITypeInfo** pptinfo) { return -1; }
virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetIDsOfNames(REFIID riid, LPOLESTR* rgszNames, UINT cNames, LCID lcid, DISPID* rgdispid) { return -1; }
virtual HRESULT __stdcall Invoke(DISPID dispidMember, REFIID riid, LCID lcid, WORD wFlags, DISPPARAMS* pdispparams, VARIANT* pvarResult, EXCEPINFO* pexcepinfo, UINT* puArgErr) { return -1; }

virtual HRESULT __stdcall raw_FloatPropertyChanging(float x, VARIANT_BOOL * cancel) { return -1; }

HRESULT __stdcall FloatPropertyChanging(float NewValue, bool *Cancel);
};

HRESULT __stdcall EventHandler::FloatPropertyChanging(float NewValue, bool *Cancel) {
printf("float value changing: NewValue = %f", NewValue);
return S_OK;
}

HRESULT __stdcall EventHandler::QueryInterface(const IID &iid, void **pp) {

if(iid == __uuidof(ICSSimpleObjectEvents) || iid == __uuidof(IUnknown) || iid == __uuidof(IDispatch))
{
    *pp = this;
    AddRef();
    return S_OK;
}
return E_NOINTERFACE;
}
```

And adding the following to get IConnectionPoint:

```
IUnknown *pUnk = NULL;

hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CSSimpleObject, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IUnknown, (void **)&pUnk);

IConnectionPointContainerPtr pContainer;
IConnectionPointPtr pConnection;
hr = pUnk->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IConnectionPointContainer), (void**) &pContainer);
hr = pContainer->FindConnectionPoint(__uuidof(ICSSimpleObjectEvents), (IConnectionPoint**) &pConnection);


EventHandler* pSink = new EventHandler;

DWORD dwAdviseCookie;

hr = pConnection->Advise((IUnknown*)pSink, &dwAdviseCookie);

pSimple_1->FloatProperty = 1.7f;
```

Setting a break point in the C# .NET COM Server at:

```
    public float FloatProperty
    {
        get { return this.fField; }
        set
        {
            bool cancel = false;   <--- I set break point here
            // Raise the event FloatPropertyChanging
            if(FloatPropertyChanging != null)  <--- FloatPropertyChanging is null here?
                FloatPropertyChanging(value, ref cancel);
            if (!cancel)
                this.fField = value;
        }
    }
```

I see that FloatPropertyChanging is null so therefore FloatPropertyChanging(...) is never called?
Anybody see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to query the COM object for its `IConnectionPointContainer` interface and retrieve a pointer to the outgoing event sink interface by calling `FindConnectionPoint`. This is described under [Architecture of Connectable Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686567.aspx).

Comment: Is there sample code that demonstrates how do this - or could someone show me some sample code that would work with above COM server

Comment: The Old New Thing has a blog entry: [An introduction to COM connection points](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/06/12/10424940.aspx). This is using ATL, though, which shouldn't be hard to translate to a plain vanilla C implementation.

Comment: Okay - I have gotten a little farther - but still something is not quite right yet; see addition to my original question above.

Comment: @Luke would you mind taking a look at the above code I know I am very close - everything works but the event?

Comment: @Kamran Amini would you mind taking a look at the code above and see if you can determine what is wrong?

Comment: See the [How to: Raise Events Handled by a COM Sink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd8bf0x3(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Are `dwAdviseCookie` and `hr` ok after the call to `Advise`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample documentation specifically calls for the event interface to be dispatch-only:

[image]

But in your code you have made it a dual interface.

```
[Guid(CSSimpleObject.EventsId), ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface ICSSimpleObjectEvents
```

I also don't see an implementation of `Invoke` in your C++ client code.  Well, I do.  It's a badly broken one.

I strongly suggest you try implementing the events through `IDispatch` because that's how the sample instructs to do it.  You can probably keep the dual interface and use [`DispInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221366.aspx) to automatically implement `IDispatch::Invoke` in terms of the v-table.

**At an absolute minimum, put a breakpoint inside your empty implementation of `Invoke` and see if that gets hit when the event is fired.**

Also, for example [this sample (not .NET)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/173906/Practical-ATL-Connection-Point-and-Two-Approaches) also instructs that `IDispatch` should be used for the event source/sink.

Comment: @BenVoight - will attempt DispInvoke and see if I can get this working using IDispatch. I'll post back - thanks!

Comment: @BenVoight - I starting to think because this is a CS EXE COM out-of-process it is extremely difficult to do developed a C++ client as an early bound (using the type library). I have tried InterfaceIsIDispatch, InterfaceIsIDual, and InterfaceIsIUnknown and can't get anything even close to working. I've spent a solid 7 days on it - I have ATL Internals book, Essential COM, and COM Programming by Example as well as all the CodeProject articles and SO info. There is really nothing newer than 5 years old and anything that works with events is a DLL COM (in-process).

Comment: It seems to me that if it was possible to receive the FloatPropertyChanging event in an unmanaged C++ application - somebody would have done it by now or developed there own version of a CS .NET COM EXE out-of-process and a combo unmanaged C++ client to receive events?

Comment: No it did not, I set one right at the front of EventHandler::Invoke and nothing?

Comment: Are `AddRef`, `Release`, and `QueryInterface` getting called?  I guess problems with `Invoke` wouldn't cure the "handler delegate is null" problem, though.

Comment: Yes all the above code seems to do everything correctly - S_OK is returned from every call including the pConnection->Advise call? FloatPropertyChanging is always null no matter what I do?

Comment: Those four IDispatch members that you've stubbed out... might be worth putting `DebugBreak();` in each of them to verify that they truly are never called.

Comment: I now have it working by resorting to ATL in my client. Still have not got it working with raw native C++.

Comment: Ben Voigt -I eventually did get a native C++ client (no ATL/MFC) to receive the event in the Invoke method. Many of your ideas and suggestions helped me in developing a new native C++ client from scratch. Just wanted to let you know - Thanks!

Comment: @Neal: Glad to hear it!  Were there any other major "Gee I wish I would have known that from the beginning" complications, or just due diligence with a debugger and the rules of the COM contract?

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement Invoke in your C++ client code, something like...

```
class EventHandler : public ICSSimpleObjectEvents
{

public:
EventHandler(void) { }
~EventHandler(void) { }

HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface(const IID &, void **);
ULONG __stdcall AddRef(void) { return 1; }
ULONG __stdcall Release(void) { return 1; }

virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetTypeInfoCount(UINT * pTypeInfoCount) { return -1; }
virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetTypeInfo(UINT itinfo, LCID lcid, ITypeInfo** pptinfo) { return -1; }
virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetIDsOfNames(REFIID riid, LPOLESTR* rgszNames, UINT cNames, LCID lcid, DISPID* rgdispid) { return -1; }
virtual HRESULT __stdcall Invoke(DISPID dispidMember, REFIID riid, LCID lcid, WORD wFlags, DISPPARAMS* pdispparams, VARIANT* pvarResult, EXCEPINFO* pexcepinfo, UINT* puArgErr);

virtual HRESULT __stdcall raw_FloatPropertyChanging(float x, VARIANT_BOOL * cancel) { return -1; }

HRESULT __stdcall FloatPropertyChanging(float NewValue, bool *Cancel);
};

HRESULT __stdcall EventHandler::Invoke(DISPID dispidMember, REFIID riid, LCID lcid, WORD wFlags, DISPPARAMS* pdispparams, VARIANT* pvarResult, 
    EXCEPINFO* pexcepinfo, UINT* puArgErr)
{
    // The riid parameter is always supposed to be IID_NULL
    if (riid != IID_NULL)
        return DISP_E_UNKNOWNINTERFACE;

    if (pdispparams) //DISPID dispIdMember
    {
        float NewValue;
        bool * pCancel;

        switch (dispidMember) {
            case 1:
                NewValue = pdispparams->rgvarg[1].fltVal;
                pCancel = (bool *)pdispparams->rgvarg[0].pboolVal;
                return FloatPropertyChanging(NewValue, pCancel);

            default:
                return E_NOTIMPL;
        }
    } else return E_NOTIMPL;
}
```